# Webrequest.BeginGetResponse is slow - alternative to verifying destination exists before getting blocked on Async call?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404

I'm having this situation:  [webrequest.begingetresponse is taking too much time when the url is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232139/webrequest-begingetresponse-is-taking-too-much-time-when-the-url-is-invalid)

However I notice that the PING command doesn't take the same amount of time.  Anyone know the equivalent .net call that ping is making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh(!)   System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()