# WPF code tried to reactivate a BindingExpression that was already marked as detached

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `WPF` application in which different user controls (images, labels, value converters) have a binding to a `listview`. So as a list view item is selected additional information is displayed in these controls.

Everything works fine, but every time I try to scroll the `listview` very fast or switch the selected item repetitively the application crashes and `internal WPF code tried to reactivate a`BindingExpression`that was already marked as detached` error is thrown.

What could it be the cause? How can I debug more in detail what binding is causing this problem? Might it be because some of the images are retrieved async from some urls and then converted to `BitmapImage` using a value converter?
Here the full details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Internal error: internal WPF code tried to reactivate a BindingExpression that was already marked as detached.
Source=PresentationFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetStatus(BindingStatusInternal status)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.SetStatus(PropertyPathStatus status)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.CompleteGetValue(AsyncGetValueRequest request)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnCompleteGetValueOperation(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindOperation.Invoke()
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.ProcessCrossThreadRequests()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at test.App.Main() in c:\bitbucket\desktop-case-cit3\test\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: To debug the issue. 1. set `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` in the `xaml` binding expression. 2. Check the Output Window while `debuging` Application. The message shown in Output Window are more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

After **a lot** of debugging I could find out that what was causing the error was the "async" binding of the image source property. The solution was to implement a helper object as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467510/826060

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to enable "caching", which is shown here on a TabControl example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization
It was my solution, because I didn't want to turn off Async.